# Upgraded from SQL Server Express to standard but CPU usage is maximum 50% on dual core

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have upgraded SQL Server Express 2008 r2 to SQL Standard Edition on amazon EC2 with a Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processors with 2 vCPU.

I have verified the edition by running this:

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

and getting

```
10.50.2500.0    SP1 Standard Edition (64-bit)
```

Also in the Windows Logs -> Application I'm seeing this MSSQLSERVER log:

```
Detected 2 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
```

I am running the below SQL Query:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, o1.object_id) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o2.object_id) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o3.object_id) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o4.object_id))
FROM sys.objects o1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o4
```

and seeing this on Windows Task Manager -> Performance:
[image]

and seeing this on windows Task Manager -> Applications:
[image]

I'm thinking that the SQL Server Express CPU limitation of 1 CPU is not removed.

- Does anybody knows why? Does it have to be something with the query?
- And how to fix it?

Comment: Source for query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24810980/122718

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see pain points of a query capture the actual execution plan via SSMS when you run it. Viewing this within SQLSentry Plan Explorer (free!!) is a bit more easy on the eyes than what SSMS will show. There are some good blog post and articles scattered around the Internet on how to read an execution plan if you need it.

Capture Actual Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: What are the steps needed for me in SSCM to configure the SQL Server Agent service correctly?

Comment: Why you posted duplicate question for second part of the question I have replied with link please check. I dont think any issue here if SQL Server is using 50 % CPU and as already pointed use execution plan to see why CPU is high.

Comment: And I don't believe the Query has something to do with it, I'm thinking that the SQL Express CPU limitation of 1 CPU is not removed.

Comment: Ok what is output of this query
 
select cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info         whatever is the number returned will be CPU used by That SQL Server instance

Comment: Added link for changing service account, works the same way for almost every service under SSCM.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Please add the part of ypou answer about Agent in [the other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71790/how-to-provision-the-sql-server-agent-service-after-sql-server-edition-upgrade). This one has been edited (and the Agent part removed.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the query, it seems that it doesn't work in parallel,
Here is the parallel version by @usr (Source for query: stackoverflow.com/a/24810980/122718) that do max ALL CPUs to 100%:

```
USE master

SELECT MyInt = CONVERT(BIGINT, o1.object_id) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o2.object_id) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o3.object_id)
INTO #temp
FROM sys.objects o1
JOIN sys.objects o2 ON o1.object_id < o2.object_id
JOIN sys.objects o3 ON o1.object_id < o3.object_id

SELECT SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, o1.MyInt) + CONVERT(BIGINT, o2.MyInt))
FROM #temp o1
JOIN #temp o2 ON o1.MyInt < o2.MyInt
```

Comment: Not all queries benefit from running in parallel.